# how to grab variable from php into a new php file

Tags: php, html, forms, http-method

I have a form

index.html

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="post">
<select name="race" style="width: 180px;">
<option value="White">White</option>
<option value="Asian">Asian</option> // 
</select>

<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"></form>
```

action_page.php

```
<?php
$varRedirect = "results.php";

  $varRace = $_POST["race"];

function redirect($url, $statusCode = 303)
{
header('location: ' .$url, true, $statusCode);
die();
}

redirect($varRedirect);

?>
```

results.php

```
<html> ...
```

I want to display the selection from index.html (white or asian)  on the results.php page but it needs to go through action_page.php because I'm going to manipulate the variable later. I receive an error when I try to do that the way I have so far.

The error I receive is "Notice: Undefined variable: varRace"
Also how I can i place stops on my action_page.php with chrome dev tools?

Comment: You had already asked a similar question

Comment: Are you closing your form?

Comment: why you may try `session` ?

Comment: </form>  your form needs this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quickest way is to append to url and pull in to new page using GET

```
redirect($varRedirect."?varA=".$varA."&varB=".$varB);
```

the rest looks ok to me. I don't see why you shouldn't be getting race